# How do I stop Ubuntu from showng all the program properties?

Tags: permissions

Every time I use my file manager to open a file I keep getting all the permission codes from properties (drwxrwxr-x)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming with "my file manager" you mean Nautilus? If so, and you're using Nautilus' list view, you can configure which columns you want to be shown. The menu item "Display columns" (or similarily named, I'm translating from German here) should give you a dialog where you can select the colums you want to see.